# Manipulating Lists in Mutable Data in Scheme

Tags: scheme, mutable

I've just begun learning about mutable data, and experiencing some problems recursively working through a list while using the `set!` command. While most of my methods work correctly in this function, the delete and cardinality functions do not, and I'm unsure as to how to solve this within this type of function.

```
(define (basic-set)
  (let ((set '()))
    (define (empty?)
      (null? set))
    (define (insert s)
      (set! set (cons s set)))
    (define (delete s)
      (cond ((equal? (car set) s)(set! set (cons (cdr set)'())))
            (else ((delete s)(cdr set)))))
    (define (element? s)
      (cond ((equal? (car set) s)#t)
            (else ((element? s)(cdr set)))))
    (define (cardinality)
      (cond ((null? set)0)
            (else
            (+ 1 ((cardinality)(cdr set))))))
    (lambda (method)
      (cond ((eq? method 'empty) empty?)
            ((eq? method 'insert) insert)
            ((eq? method 'delete) delete)
            ((eq? method 'element) element?)
            ((eq? method 'cardinality) cardinality)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful with the way you implement `delete`, `element?` and `cardinality` - these procedures have to iterate over the set that's stored as mutable data, and for that you have to pass the set as a parameter, I'd do that using a named `let`.

Also, implementing `delete` is tricky, the correct way to do it is to eliminate the element and then update the state at the end. This is what I mean:

```
(define (basic-set)
  (let ((set '()))
    (define (empty?)
      (null? set))
    (define (insert s)
      (set! set (cons s set)))
    (define (delete s)
      (define (helper set)
        (cond ((null? set) '())
              ((equal? (car set) s) (cdr set))
              (else (cons (car set) (helper (cdr set))))))
      (set! set (helper set)))
    (define (element? s)
      (let loop ((set set))
        (cond ((null? set) #f)
              ((equal? (car set) s) #t)
              (else (loop (cdr set))))))
    (define (cardinality)
      (let loop ((set set))
        (cond ((null? set) 0)
              (else (+ 1 (loop (cdr set)))))))
    (lambda (method)
      (cond ((eq? method 'empty) empty?)
            ((eq? method 'insert) insert)
            ((eq? method 'delete) delete)
            ((eq? method 'element) element?)
            ((eq? method 'cardinality) cardinality)))))
```

For example:

```
(define s (basic-set))

((s 'insert) 'x)
((s 'insert) 'y)
((s 'element) 'x)
=> #t
((s 'cardinality))
=> 2
((s 'delete) 'x)
((s 'cardinality))
=> 1
((s 'empty))
=> #f
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method here is to anonymous functions to match the external interface arity to the internal methods arity like so. Certainly uglier than Oscar's solutions, but sometimes it's best to make it work before you worry about pretty.

```
(define (basic-set)
  (let ((set '()))
    (define (empty?)
      (null? set))
    (define (insert s)
      (set! set (cons s set)))
    (define (delete s L)
     (set! set 
       (let loop ((L L))
         (cond ((null? L) '())            
               ((equal? (car L) s) (cdr L))
               (else (cons (car L) (loop (cdr L)))))))
    (define (element? s L)
      (cond ((equal? (car L) s) #t)
            (else (element? s  (cdr L)))))
    (define (cardinality L)
      (cond ((null? L) 0)
            (else
             (+ 1 ((cardinality)(cdr L))))))
    (lambda (method)
      (cond ((eq? method 'empty) empty?)
            ((eq? method 'insert) insert)
            ((eq? method 'delete) (lambda (s) (delete s set)))
            ((eq? method 'element) (lambda (s) (element? s set)))
            ((eq? method 'cardinality) (lambda () (cardinality set)))))))
```